# foreach loop - if greater than count or else

Tags: php, foreach, if-statement

I have a foreach loop in php.

When the loop is greater than 2 items I would like to display some text instead of the loop. Is this possible?

For example: A loop of 2 or less items shows= item 1, item2

The loop of more items shows the text = Mulitple items.

The example code for indication:

```
$count++; 
foreach($attValConfig as $attValConfigSingle) { 
if ($attValConfigSingle["frontend_label"] == "LABELTEXT") { 
echo ('<div class="attributes_row">Text</div>');

foreach($attValConfigSingle['values'] as $attValConfigSingleVal) {

if ($count++ > 2)   { echo 'SomeNewText'; }
else echo "<option>"list of items"</option>";
```

Comment: It seem that you already have your solution (break). Give us more detail if possible about the data being passed and if the loop is working if this doesn't fix your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to `break` in your if statement:

```
if ($count++ > 2)   { 
    echo 'SomeNewText'; 
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`count`](http://php.net/count) the array before looping:

```
if(count($attValConfigSingle['values']) > 2) {
    // More than 2 items
    echo "Lots of things";
} else {
    // 2 items or less
    foreach($attValConfigSingle['values'] as $value) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

---

### Edit:

Maybe I didn't understand you correctly. If you want the text:

> item 1, item 2, other items...

Then you need to use `break` to break out of your loop:

```
foreach($attValConfigSingle['values'] as $attValConfigSingleVal) {
    if ($count++ > 2) {
       echo 'SomeNewText';
       break;
    } else {
        echo "<option>"list of items"</option>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a variable in which you store your text built during the foreach loops. When you're out of it, print this string if count is less than 3, your other text otherwise.